# Java not utulising imported certificates into cacerts with keytool for JVM: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, jvm, ssl-certificate, keytool

So I am accessing `microsoftonline.com` and `graph.microsoft.com`. For both these sites, I went to the sites in the browser and downloaded the certs in base 64 formats, imported them both with the following command.

```
c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib>keytool -importcert  -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias microsoftgraph -file C:\Users\me\Desktop\graphcert64.cer -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

And I got the message certificate was added to keystore. However, I still seem to be getting the error,

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

According to the eclipse, the JDK I am using is `jdk.1.8.0_161`

How can I troubleshoot what is going on here?

Comment: Can you post the code where you set the truststore?

Comment: I dont set the trust store, I thought I just had to import it into the cacerts that already exist in the jdk?